# How to load different templates in angular route on the basis of some conditions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am new to AngularJs and trying to load template on the basis of `Id` in angular route.

Here is my route :

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .state('template', {
       url:'/template/{id}',
       templateUrl: 'views/pages/template_main.html',
       controller: 'TemplateController',
       resolve: {
           loadMyDirectives:function($ocLazyLoad){
               return $ocLazyLoad.load(
               {
                   name:'myApp',
                   files:[
                     'scripts/directives/template1/template1.js',
                   ]
               })
            }
        }
    })
```

**How can I achieve this?**

if `id==1` then it will load this:  `'scripts/directives/template1/template1.js'`

if `id==2`  then it will load this: `'scripts/directives/template1/template2.js`'

How can I make conditions in route. Any suggestions?

Comment: You talk about loading a different template, but give an example of `.js` file. Templates are HTML, not JS. What exactly is `template1.js` vs. `template2.js`?

Comment: `template1.js `and `template2.js` are my directive inside this I am loading templates like `template1.html` and `template2.html`